# authentication with has_secure_password and sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_secure_password
        attr_accessor :account

        has_one :company 
        has_one :employee
        has_many :messages

        def self.authenticate(user, password)
            user = User.find_by_user(user)

            unless user && user.authenticate(password)
                redirect_to new_session_path
            end

            user        
        end 

    end
```

for some reason that I dont get the code inside of the `unless` condition dont recognize any rails code, like that `redirect_to new_session_path` or any other path, and throws this:

`NameError in SessionsController#create`

`undefined local variable or method "new_session_path" for #<Class:0x2f0e998>`

I did try a `raise` but was the same, someone knows why that would be?
thanks for your help.

*stack trace*:

```
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in "method_missing"
app/models/user.rb:14:in "authenticate"
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:6:in "create"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in "send_action"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in "process_action"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in "process_action"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in "block in process_action"
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in "_run__439917834__process_action__1037818096__callbacks"
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in "__run_callback"
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in "_run_process_action_callbacks"
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in "run_callbacks"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in "process_action"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in "process_action"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in "block in process_action"
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in "block in instrument"
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in "instrument"
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in "instrument"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in "process_action"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in "process_action"
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in "process_action"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in "process"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in "process"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in "dispatch"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in "dispatch"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in "block in action"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in "call"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in "dispatch"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in "call"
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in "block in call"
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in "each"
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in "call"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in "call"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in "call"
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in "call"
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in "call"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in "call"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in "call"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in "call"
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in "context"
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in "call"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in "call"
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in "call"
activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in "call"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in "block in call"
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in "_run__813925422__call__171472149__callbacks"
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in "__run_callback"
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in "_run_call_callbacks"
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in "run_callbacks"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in "call"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in "call"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in "call"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in "call"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in "call"
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in "call_app"
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in "call"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in "call"
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in "call"
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in "call"
activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in "call"
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in "call"
actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in "call"
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in "call"
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in "call"
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in "call"
railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in "call"
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in "service"
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in "service"
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in "run"
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in "block in start_thread"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Models should not be responsible for redirecting as this is the responsibility of controllers. Try pulling the redirect out of your model and into your controller. The authenticate method should just verify if the user is valid and let the controller take appropriate action based upon that result.

Comment: but then is that what is causing the problem? I understand if is a bad application of the MVC but still dont see why dont recognize the methods, I will have to put it in the controller but I really would like to know why that happens..

Comment: You'll run into issues because redirect_to and new_session_path won't be defined in your scope. Sachin.Singh suggests including the routes helpers which should allow for the new_session_path method to work, but you'll still be missing the redirect_to method, which is an action controller method.

Answer (score 0):

write this in your user model.

```
 include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

or,

use instead of new_session_path

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.new_session_path
```

Comment: thanks but not working yet, and for some reason now i get this:  `SystemStackError in SessionsController#new` `stack level too deep`

Comment: I just see Application Trace, Framework Trace, Full Trace sorry but dont know how to get the stack trace.

Comment: with the `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` i get: 

`actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70`

Comment: yes i did try that one too and get the same: 

`actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70`

Comment: thank you for your help, i guess is not possible do it this way, gonna change the code so it returns `nil` if the authentication fails, use `.nil?` and then redirect from the controller, but still is weird that the model dont has access to that methods i think.